# How to quickly replicate/update local library under $R_LIBS_USER?

Tags: r

Suppose that

1. the version of R I have installed is 3.3.1;
2. my environment variable `$R_LIBS_USER` is set to `$HOME/my/R_lib/%V`; and
3. I have a directory `$HOME/my/R_lib/3.3.1` containing a large number of packages I've installed over time.

Now I want to upgrade my version of R, to 3.4.1, say.

I'm looking for a convenient way to install a new collection of packages under the new directory `$HOME/my/R_lib/3.4.1` that is the "version-3.4.1-equivalent" of the library I currently have under `$HOME/my/R_lib/3.3.1`.

(IOW, I'm looking for a functionality similar to what one can do with Python's `pip` installer's "freeze" option, which, essentially, produces the input one would have to give the installer in the future to reproduce the current installation.)

Comment: I guess you could start by copying your 3.3.1 directory to 3.4.1 and then run `update.packages()`

Comment: Maybe [installr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html) ?

Comment: In addition to the other excellent answers my personal twist on it would be to replace `install.packages` in the @plannapus answer with `p_load` from `pacman` for its various virtues in terms of syntax, automated checking of installed/available versions, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use function `installed.packages` for that purpose. Namely:

```
installed.packages(lib.loc = "$HOME/my/R_lib/3.3.1")
```

The returned object contains a lot of informations (most fields from each package `DESCRIPTION` file) but the names of the packages are in the first column. So something like the following should do the trick:

```
inst <- installed.packages(lib.loc = "$HOME/my/R_lib/3.3.1")
install.packages(inst[,1], lib="$HOME/my/R_lib/3.4.1", dependencies=FALSE)
```

---

To answer the additional question in the comments:

If your old library contained packages from other sources than CRAN, you will have to do some gymnastic based on the content of the `DESCRIPTION` files, and thus will depend on how well the package author documented it.
Argument `field` in `installed.packages` allows you to select some additional fields from those files. Fields of interest to determine the source of a package are fields `Repository`, `URL` and `Maintainer`. Here are some ideas on how to split them apart:

CRAN vs non-CRAN:

```
inst <- installed.packages(lib.loc = "$HOME/my/R_lib/3.3.1", 
                           fields=c("URL","Repository","Maintainer"))
inst <- as.data.frame(inst, row.names=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
cran <- inst[inst$Repository%in%"CRAN",]
non_cran <- inst[!inst$Repository%in%"CRAN" & !inst$Priority%in%"base",]
```

Bioconductor packages:

```
bioc <- inst[grepl("Bioconductor",inst$Maintainer),]
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(pkgs=bioc$Packages)
```

Github packages:

```
git <- non_cran[grepl("github", non_cran$URL),]
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
for(i in seq(nrow(git))){
    install_github(repo=gsub("http://github.com/","",git$URL[i]))
}
```

Comment: What about for bioconductor or GitHub packages, etc?

Comment: @thc indeed i haven t thought of those ones, i ll try to add something as soon as i can, to catch those.